Does anyone else have a mysterious UID appear in their ADB? (-253)
I input the command adb shell dumpsys netstats detail and found  "-253". The "-253" doesn't have any package name, and this is the only mention of "-253" I could find in the ADB. It's been using data which is annoying because I have a very limited plan, and I can't figure out what it is
(Aside from "f2fs gc-253" which shares the "-253" but I believe it to be unrelated)
If anyone has an android of any model, with the latest updates + security patches, could you see whether it appears on your mobile? I'm trying to work out if this is a localized issue or if others have the same
(If you don't want to bother with ADB, you can just use a specific data monitoring application, this is the only one able to capture the Unknown)
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.datacounter&hl=en_US"
it should be "Unknown (uid-253)" under yearly usage
but it's not essential
Thanks

You can try using WhatsRunning //App is developed by a valued contributor on this site Irfan

@beeshyams Can't use it because of OPPO not allowing splitscreen with the settings app, thus unable to pair it.

@beeshyams I'm not sure whether this is a quirk with the oppo skin but the pairing code resets every time I leave my settings to enter it into "Whatsrunning", so when I enter it into the app, it's already invalid. though I presume that's why the help manual said to use splits screen

@beeshyams  I'll give that a try, I'm going to guess you don't have an ADB on hand to plug in the netstats command? (unless you don't have an android/newer android then don't worry about it)
